# How to properly clone a visualstudio.com TFS Git repository from a command line?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to use command line git to clone a TFS-based Git repository located at visualstudio.com. The actual address of the repo is

```
https://kalamon.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/gitp
```

I have enabled "alternate credentials" in my profile, I have also set a username alias that does not contain a `@` (because this messes up `git clone`). Yet, all attempts to clone the repo, or pull it or whatever else results in this error:

```
Cloning into 'gitp'...
fatal: https://kalamon.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/gitp/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I tried this with a different Git repository on the same account with the same result.

I have tried all kind of things - like putting `<username>:<password>@` after `https://` or using `_netrc`, but nothing works. Same error happens no matter what I try. I am not prompted for credentials on the command line.

When I use `curl` to get https://kalamon.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/gitp/info/refs and provide basic authentication, I get them without an issue.

Cloning from VS2013 UI works fine. However, I really need to be able to do this from the command line, because I need to make cloning work from scripted environment.

Does anybody have any ide what could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I did some digging, and it turns out that only my account is affected. When I tried on a different account on visualstudio.com, things work just fine.

I also did some tracing, and it turned out that on my account the response from Git server is somewhat strange (I would say incorrect) - instead of responding with 401 error code ("unauthenticated"), the server responds with 302 ("redirect") - redirecting to login page. On properly working account, the server properly responds with a 401 code and things work fine. It is as if on my account the "alternate credentials" setting is not set up and the server does not allow basic authentication at all.

Have I just found a problem with visualstudio.com?

Comment: I have suffered similar issues when proxies are involved as well. Are you connecting to the repo using a proxy?

Comment: nope, no proxy. The connection is direct

Comment: How you installed Git, which version, from which shell you call? Have you checked the Credential Manager for stale user/passwords?

Comment: The presence of alternate credentials does not control whether you get a 401 - can you copy and paste the URL directly from the code explorer?  Does that change the behavior?  Where is the 302 redirecting you?

Comment: I have same error but my account works on my desktop computer and everything works with another account

Answer (score 3):

I just tried on my VSO account using Git Bash and works fine.

```
$ git clone https://user%40example.com:password@account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Repository%20Name "Repository Name"
```

`%40` is `@` URL-escaped.

Comment: I must still be doing something wrong, because this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I [found](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/226164/force-username-prompt-in-git-clone) that if you update git to a newer version (I had version 1.7.1, after updating had 1.7.12.4) it started to prompt for username and password. Then you don't need to provide the username and or password in the clone statement.